# Maven uses different dependencies depending on which machine it runs?

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, artifactory, building

I have a project that is building properly on my local machine. In my company we use a server machine to do the continuous integration but that machine has no connection to the internet. So I have set up artifactory and copied my whole repository to it. Then connected jenkins with this artifactory. So jenkins should do the build without any problem no? As it has the same setup as my local project.

After a few seconds of building a message pops up that he can't find a dependency:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project crs-data: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.ing.crs:crs-data:jar:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to collect dependencies for
>   [com.ing.crs:crs-framework:jar:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT (compile),
>   org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all:jar:2.3.0 (provided),
>   ibm.websphere:j2ee6:jar:8.5.0 (provided),
>   ibm.websphere:jpaThinClient:jar:8.5.0 (provided),
>   com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1 (compile),
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3 (test), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test),
>   mockito-all:mockito-all:jar:1.8.4 (test), oracle.jdbc:ojdbc6:jar:11.2
>   (test), com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.167 (test),
>   ibm.websphere:embeddedEJBContainer:jar:8.5.0 (test),
>   com.ing.be:bbllib.DeploymentInfo:jar:2.3.2 (provided)]: **Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4: Could
>   not transfer artifact commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:pom:1.4** from/to
>   crs.maven.repo
>   (http://sdbeapp00433.devbe.development:8082/artifactory/repo): Access
>   denied to:
>   http://sdbeapp00433.devbe.development:8082/artifactory/repo/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.pom
>   -> [Help 1]

But locally the build doesn't even use commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:pom:1.4. How is that possible????

The pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>com.ing.crs</groupId>
    <artifactId>crs-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../crs-parent-pom/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>crs-data</artifactId>
<version>${project.crs-data.version}</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <properties>
            <dbDictionary>disableAlterSeqenceIncrementBy=true</dbDictionary>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>stubs</id>
        <properties>
            <dbDictionary></dbDictionary>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <!-- CRS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ing.crs</groupId>
        <artifactId>crs-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${project.crs-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee6</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpaThinClient</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mockito-all</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.167</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibm.websphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>embeddedEJBContainer</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ing.be</groupId>
        <artifactId>bbllib.DeploymentInfo</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>crs-data</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>target/crs-data</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>          
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerArguments>-Aopenjpa.source=7 -Aopenjpa.metamodel=true</compilerArguments>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/metamodel</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enhancer_for_test</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>**/entities/**/*.class</includes>
                        <includes>**/data/**/*.class</includes>
                        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>                        
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-test-persistence</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <!--backup the "proper" persistence.xml-->
                                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.proper"/>
                                <!--replace the "proper" persistence.xml with the "test" version-->
                                <!-- copy file="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/-->
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>restore-persistence</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <!--restore the "proper" persistence.xml-->
                                <copy file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml.proper" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                            <customClasspathLayout>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Build-Time>${timestamp}</Build-Time>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
            only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        openjpa-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.openjpa
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        openjpa-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you give us some others information about this **Should build without any problem no?**  What are you building (in addition to share your pom.xml)?

Comment: commons-dbcp can be used by one of your dependency/plugin. Copy your ~/.m2 to ~/jenkins/.m2 and try again. The second solution is to configure proxy and external repositories in artifactory.

Comment: The problem is located in this: `Access denied to: http://sdbeapp00433.devbe.development:8082/artifactory/repo/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.pom `...

Answer (score 1):

Your build is failing since Maven is failing to download dependencies from Artifactory due to an authentication issue:

```
Access denied to: http://sdbeapp00433.devbe.development:8082/artifactory/repo/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.pom
```

If you will look at the Artifactory access.log you should see a matching log entry about a denied download.

If you are working with the Artifactory Jenkins plugin, you can configure the resolver credentials as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringArtifactoryServer%28s%29).
If you are not using the Artifactory Jenkins plugin, you should configure the Maven authentication as described in ["Working With Maven"](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven). This requires adding the correct credentials to the Maven settings.xml file.
A third option is allowing anonymous access to Artifactory as described [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security). This will allow resolving dependencies from Artifactory without authentication.

commons-dbcp is probably a transitive dependency. If you want to find its origin, you should use the [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) goal of the Maven dependency plugin which displays the dependency tree for this project.

As a side note, you should not use the "repo" repository. This is a default global virtual repository which effectively aggregates all other repositories. By configuring Maven with this URL, any request for an artifact will go through Artifactory which will search through all of the local and remote repositories defined in the system. It is better to work with a virtual repository which aggregates only the relevant repositories for your build.

Comment: There is no authentication error with artifactory. It says that because it can not find the pom that it tries to open. But the question is why does it need that file when it is not used when I build locally.

Thus a different build behaviour when I build locally vs build via jenkins.

Comment: Try using dependency:tree for finding the origin of the commons-dbcp dependency. Are there any diffs between the build env in Jenkins and your local one: Maven version, Maven profile being used? did you try building locally with a clean Maven cache (local repository)? In addition, did you try downloading the commons-dbcp dependency from Artifactory?